# COUNTIF over a moving window

Tags: rstudio

I have a column wherein datapoints have been assigned a "1" or "2". I would like to use a function similar to COUNTIF in Excel, but over a moving window, e.g. =COUNTIF(G2:G31, 2) to determine how many "2"s exist in that given window

[image: snap]

Comment: I have tried using rollapply:
inactive <- rollapply(state, width = 20, by = 1, FUN = sum(state == '2'))

but receive the following error:
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'sum(state == "2")' is not a function, character or symbol

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [`tibbletime`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/tibbletime/vignettes/TT-03-rollify-for-rolling-analysis.html).

1) Since you are interested in state being `1` or `2`, we can recode it into a logical (boolean). Assuming your data.frame is named `df`,

```
df$state <- df$state == 2
```

2) Logicals are cool, because we can simply sum them, and get the number of `TRUE` values:

```
# total number of rows with state == 2:
sum(df$state)
```

3) Make a rollify function, cf. the link:

```
library(tibbletime)
rolling_sum <- rollify(sum, window = 30)
df$countif = rolling_sum(df$state)
```

This approach does however not solve the leading 29 rows. For those you can in your case use:

```
df$countif[1:29] <- cumsum(df$state[1:29])
```

Comment: I'm just working through your solution now, but I am receiving an error message that R cannot find the function "rollify". I have loaded the libraries 'tibbletime,' 'dplyr,' and 'tidyr'

Comment: Which version of `tibbletime` are you using? Try pasting the output from `sessionInfo()`. Try calling it as `tibbletime::rollify`.